# jQuery replaceAll() function

Tags: jquery

I want to replace every link by an input box whose value is the URL of the link. I would like to use the jQuery replaceAll() function. The standard format is

```
$(content).replaceAll(target);
```

My question is: how do you refer to the target object? In other words, in the following code, what should I replace *TheCurrentLink* with?

```
$('<input>').attr('value', TheCurrentLink.href}).replaceAll($("a"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something more like this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var $a = $(this);
    $a.replaceWith($('<input/>').attr('value', $a.attr('href')));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("a").replaceWith(function() {
   return "<input type='text' value='"+$(this).attr("href")+"' />";
});
```

Test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g78u8/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `replaceWith()` instead:

```
    $('a').each(function(){
       $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).attr('href') +  '" />');
    });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/6KP4H/

Working Example 2, added logic to convert inputs back into links: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/6KP4H/1/